# AllowUserVariables in connection string - SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-express

I am trying to add "AllowUserVariables=true" in my connection string to access SQL Server Express using C#. But an `Keyword not supported: 'allowuservariables'.` exception is thrown.
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

Only in ms SQL server, you can run this command:

```
<add name="ConnectionString_LIVE_customer_support" connectionString="server=REMOVED;port=REMOVED;User Id=REMOVED;password=REMOVED;Persist Security Info=True;database=customer_support;Sql Server Mode=True;Allow User Variables=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```